# Sending ParsePush notifications with Back4App

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Before migrating to Back4App from Parse, I could easily send a push notification like this by querying the Installation object of the user I want to send a push notification to:

```
    private void handleLikeNotification(ParseObject messageObject) {
        String userId = messageObject.getParseObject(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER).getObjectId();
        String result = messageObject.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TEXT);

        // Initiate installation query
        ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        pushQuery.whereEqualTo("userId", userId);

        // Create push notification
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setQuery(pushQuery);
        push.setMessage("Liked by " + ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() + ": " + result);
        push.sendInBackground();


        // Check condition and send push notification
        if (!userId.equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId())) {
            send(notification);
        }

    protected void send(ParseObject notification) {
        notification.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                        // success!

                } else {
                        // notification failed to send!

                }
            }
        });
     }
```

I have followed their documentation and my Receiver works correctly because I can send myself and my users notifications through their dashboard.

My question for StackOverflow is why can't I create and send push notifications like this through my app? This identical code works for my app that's still hosted by the original Parse hosting solution.

My push notifications are now being served by GCM, so I suppose I need to send them using a GCM class but I don't know where to look.

My best assumption at this point is that the `ParsePush` class doesn't work with my current configuration. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked Back4App's documentation and it seems that they have some steps on how to set the Client Push, which seems to be the problem that you're having.

According to it, you'll need to put your GCM Sender Id right after the Parse initialization like this:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("GCMSenderId", "Your GCM Sender ID here");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

And after it, just use ParsePush query:

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
// Here you can personalize your pushQuery
// Add channels as you like, or remove this part to reach everyone
LinkedList<String> channels = new LinkedList<String>();
channels.add("group_1");
// Change this "message" String to change the message sent
String message = "Back4App says Hi!";
// In case you want to send data, use this
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"rating\": \"5 stars\"}");

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
// Set our Installation query
push.setQuery(pushQuery);
// Sets the channels
push.setChannels(channels);
// Sets the message
push.setMessage(message);
// Sets the data
push.setData(data);
push.sendInBackground();
```

The documentation also say that you'll need to enable a Client Push option.

Maybe that should help on solving your question.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works. I've seen figured out how to enable cloud-based notifications through their service as well but client push is so much easier to implement and you don't have to write any extra javascript. Cheers.